# How to use nickname instead full name Apple Developer Account?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-developer

I want to throw an app into AppStore, so I ask if there's any way to, without being a company, I could use a nickname, so I don't need to use my full name.

Anyone help?

Comment: It's fairly easy (and free) to get a DUNS number and register as an organization. https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/   Whether one should do that is a different question, although if say you're self-employed as a developer, I don't see why you shouldn't be allowed to register as an organization. Although keep in mind that after you sign up for DUNS you might get lots of telemarketers trying to sell you office supplies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. For most things like that, you could create a DBA ("Doing Business As") to operate under, but Apple requires that you register as either an individual (with your legal name) or an organization with a legal entity. Your registered name is used in the App Store.

See [Before You Enroll.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)

You wouldn't be able to register as an individual using a DBA, and you wouldn't be able to register as an organization without a legal entity (LLC, etc.)